# Free pointer offset no longer valid?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, glibc, pointer-arithmetic

I could have sworn this code should work, but it seems now it segfaults. Anyone know if this has always been the case or a change in glibc?

```
   ....
   char *tmp = malloc(50);
   tmp = &tmp[10];
   free(tmp);   // segfault
   // I thought as long as the pointer was within a valid memory block,   
   // the free was valid. Obviously I know not to double free, but this   
   // means any pointer offsets must be kept along with the original malloced 
   // pointer for the free operation.
```

Comment: Nope, you *must* `free` the very same value you were given. **§ 7.22.3.3** *...if the argument does
not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: You can't just index into a block of dynamically allocated memory and expect to be able to free it at that point.  If you allocate a block of memory, use the initial portion of it, and want to free the rest, the correct way is to call `realloc`, giving it the original pointer and the *used* byte count.  E.g. `p = malloc(100); p = realloc(p, 40);` will retain the first 40 bytes.  Note that the pointer value may change, so you need to use the pointer returned by `realloc`.

Comment: I wonder why this is not allowed. I cannot see any problems that might arise from it. It's unambigous what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to doing a lot of string manipulation, like tmp = strdup("   Hello   "); and then using pointers to areas to skip whitespace. I guess I just assumed I could free a pointer within the original block.

Comment: klutt, yeah it seems malloc already knows the block sizes, so I don't see why free wouldn't see if the pointer is within a valid block.

Comment: Note too that although a pointer to one past a valid memory range is a *valid* pointer (but can't be dereferenced) it isn't within the range of the memory that was allocated.

Comment: @KaibutsuX Doesn't work that way, and never has worked that way. You either need to keep the original pointer, or you need a mechanism that allows the code to compute the original pointer.

Comment: @klutt Seriously?  How would you implement this?  `malloc` keeps information about the memory block immediately before the allocated memory.  How do you expect it to find that information if someone passes a pointer into the middle of block?  How would it know how large the block is?  It's no mystery why this doesn't work.

Comment: @TomKarzes I don't see any big problems implementing it. Basically, it's equivalent to figure out which file a block belongs to on a harddrive. Maybe it's not a good thing to implement, but it's certainly possible and also without too much effort.

Comment: @TomKarzes Consider those headers malloc creates. It has to be a low level way of looping through them, so then you just do a `for header in headers: if(header.contains(address)) return true`

Comment: @klutt That goes without saying.  The point is that it needs to be a fast, lightweight process.  Keeping a bunch of data structures around and then doing searches to try to find it would be much slower, take more memory, and serve no useful purpose.  It's no accident that no one has bothered to implement such a slow and useless mechanism when you can just call `realloc` with the original pointer (which you are guaranteed to have) to get the same effect.

Comment: @klutt You are correct that a loop would be needed. You seem to be overlooking the performance problems with such a loop. Imagine the code has called `malloc` N times. Then your proposed mechanism is O(N^2) to free the memory, in the worst case. Given that N could be in the millions, that clearly unworkable.

Comment: @klutt As I said, your suggestion serves no purpose but to slow it down and obscure the code that uses it.  Bad idea, bad design.

Comment: You are right. I overlooked the performance problems.

Comment: @user3386109 And the fact that it doesn't solve any problem.  There is absolutely no need for such a mechanism.  It's a solved problem.  Not to mention the fact that allowing random pointers into dynamic memory to be freed would mask bugs.

Comment: @TomKarzes True. It's not good design. But to be fair, when they decided that this is UB, I don't think they had those bugs in mind. I'm pretty sure the guys who designed early C stopped with the thought that it's not necessary since that's a responsibility you can give to the programmer.

Comment: @klutt `malloc`, `realloc`, etc. have been around since long, long before ANSI C.  They needed a fast, clean, lightweight dynamic memory allocation system, and they implemented the first version of `malloc` to serve that purpose.  But it's not unique to C.  Many languages support something similar.  I've designed and implemented dynamic memory library myself.  But they all have one thing in common:  When resizing or freeing memory, you always pass the pointer that was returned to you.  You never add some offset to it and then expect it to hunt for what you already have.

Comment: @klutt Even if it were fast and had low overhead, you still wouldn't want to support that.  It invites bugs and bad code.  The first thing you'd want to do is disable it.

Comment: @klutt pretty much everything in C needs good housekeeping from the coder. You should know, it is raw.

Comment: @TomKarzes Alright already. Everybody agrees with you :) The horse is long dead, and beaten to a pulp.

Comment: @user3386109 I just saw it moving :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet

```
   char *tmp = malloc(50);
   tmp = &tmp[10];
   free(tmp);   // segfault
   // I thought as long as the
```

is invalid because after this statement

```
   tmp = &tmp[10];
```

the pointer tmp does not have the address of the extent of the dynamically allocated memory. So the next statement

```
free(tmp);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (7.22.3.3 The free function)

Otherwise, **if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, **the behavior is undefined**.

You could write

```
   tmp = &tmp[10];
   //...
   free(tmp - 10 );
```

Or it seems what you need is to reallocate the early allocated memory like

```
   char *tmp = malloc(50);
   char *tmp2 = realloc( tmp, 10 );

   if ( tmp2 != NULL ) tmp = tmp2;
```

Comment: while I get the reasoning, what I am wanting is not to change the size, I just don't want to have to keep multiple pointers around. if tmp points to malloced memory and a, b, c, d and e point to areas within it, it seems like I should be able to lose references to all but 1 and still free the memory area.

Comment: @KaibutsuX If you have a pointer that points to the early allocated memory then you of course can to free the allocated memory using the pointer, I answered your question based on the code snippet you presented.

Comment: @KaibutsuX Well, as long as you have the size, you can get the orignal. You could have used `free(&tmp[-10])`

Comment: @klutt, yeah, although the real use case would be a function that returns &tmp[x] and the caller wouldn't know the original src pointer

Comment: @AlexLop. In his code he wants to free memory starting from the element with the index 10.

Comment: Must be all in my head or I got lucky with undefined behavior, because I could have sworn I had done this before, but either way good to know now.

Comment: @KaibutsuX: If anything you got *unlucky* because the behavior you observed gave you a mistaken perception of the language.